# Why is my stacksize function returning NONE

Tags: python, python-2.7, stack

```
class stack:
  def __init__(self)

  def stacksize(self):
       Size=len(self.stack)
       Print ('size is', size)
```

It returns
Size is 4  #assuming list is of size four
None

And how can I access the top most element in that stack

Comment: You haven't assigned any object to stack. The function returns None because you haven't returned anything from the function

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the code you posted is complete, but your **init** function is not complete.  Use a 'pass' to declare functions that don't have any real code.  Secondly, stacksize is returning None because you are not actually returning anything.

```
class stack:
  def __init__(self):
      pass # Add this line of code

  def stacksize(self):
       Size=len(self.stack)
       Print ('size is', size)
       return size # Add this line of code to return the value.
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's go in detail over your code.

The first thing I noticed is that you need to add the **pass** keyword to any block that is empty in python. Also, you are forgetting to open your block by not using a color. So, if I run the code as is, I get this:

```
File "main.py", line 2    def __init__(self)
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Going down to the second method, in the first letter of the print method (P), you notice that is in uppercase. In programming, naming conventions are important, so **print()** should be all in lowercase. Let's take a look at the errors marked in the second method:

[image]

As mentioned above, correct **print()**. Moving on to the next thing, **Size** is underlined in green. I would suggest you get a linting program for your code, in this case, by convention variables should start with a lowercase letter. If we fix those two things, the state of your code is this:

[image]

ok, nice, things are getting better now. But, why self has a red underline? The reason of that **self** contextualize the current instance calling this method of this class. the issue is that the stack property has not been declared, in order to do this, change your code to be like this:

```
class stack:
  def __init__(self):
      self.stack = []

  def stacksize(self):
       size = len(self.stack)
       print('size is', size)
```

Notice that I deleted pass, and assigned an empty list to the stack member variable. Of course you will decide that the **stack** member variable will be, in this case I just went to add it as a list.

Ok, now, the final question would be, why **size** is None? With the code changes I added, it should now return **zero (0)** because the stack list is empty, but there is a list.

Classes by convention start with an uppercase letter.

[image]

Finally, how could you access the top element of the stack? Like this:

[image]

The context of this code of course is outside the class context, notice it does not have **self.**, but it should be the same for your **self.stack**.

I hope this helps pal! :)

Comment: Thanks alot I've debugged all the code and it works out

Comment: No problem! :).